# Application error

Tags: delphi, odbc, delphi-2010, sap-ase

I am facing below error when i am accessing the exe of my build which is built in Delphi 10 with Unidac.Can any one point out me..what went wrong...

Exception EUniError in module unidac140.bpl at 0001031C. 
Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 126(Sybase ASE ODBC Driver)

Thanks

Comment: It looks like a driver could not be loaded.

Comment: 126 is The specified module could not be
found. That's what you get when you call LoadLibrary and the DLL cannot be located.

Comment: Make sure the ODBC driver is installed and configured.

Comment: I think, you need to update your Sybase ASE ODBC Driver if possible.

Comment: Maybe this similar question can help. http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=20782&sid=f023b7ae18e7c68a93b20e586f51463b

Comment: Driver is not installed properly re-installed drivers again.